# How to structure UI dependent on onscreen keyboards?

Tags: guidelines, keyboard, tablet

We are developing a Windows 8 tablet application but this should be applicable to every tablet OS. There are several textboxes which open up the onscreen keyboard when they get focus.

In most cases this seems a bit jarring to the users since the keyboard uses up more than half of their screen. In some cases the inevitable scrolling seems to create some confusion in others we used Flyouts (hovering popups which are moved upward when the keyboard opens) which seem to have the same effect.

Are there best practices to cope with this problems? Which solution (e.g. Flyouts, scrolling) is the most comfortable for the user?

Comment: Having some trouble understanding what specifically your problem is.  Are users not able to move between fields easily?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this keyboard dominance is standard for all touchscreen devices and most device manufacturer' user interface guidelines request that application developers use the system keyboard and not create their own.

As a result, there is not a lot that can be done to help make forms usable on these devices. **Use scrolling** and make sure there is enough room for the user to scroll (allow space in the layout for the "scroll" gesture). Luckily, users know what to expect from forms.